# C++ Vector and Functions - Cannot get the program to work. Need help,

Tags: c++, function, stl

Hey guys? I'm new to the whole C++ Standard Library thing, but for the devil of me, I cannot figure out why this program is not giving me the output I hope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

/*
create_vec should initialise my vector and return an iterator pointing to 
it.
*/
template <typename s>
  typename std::vector<s>::iterator create_vec(s var) {
     std::vector<s> tempVec;
     tempVec.push_back(var);
     auto itr = tempVec.begin();
     return itr;
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int>::iterator itr = create_vec<int>(148);
   std::cout << *itr << "was passed." << std::endl;
   return 0;
   }
```

O/P : 0 was passed to the create vec function

p.s ignore all the std's. I want to know at each moment where i got each type, function etc.

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot simply create an std::vector in main? Is this for practice?

Comment: Unrelated, but your use of the `std::` prefix is fine. I *never* use `using namespace std`, and rather use the namespace prefix.

Comment: yes, this is for practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `tempVec` is local inside the `create_vec` function. When the function returns the vector object is destructed, leaving you with an iterator to something which doesn't exist any more. That leads to *undefined behavior* when you try to use the iterator.

Isn't the purpose of the `create_vec` function to return *the vector* instead? The name of the function suggests it should do so.

Comment: For an additional note, to return the vector, you can return std::move(tempVec), though I'd like to hear whether there are compiler optimizations that render the std::move unnecessary.

Comment: @synchronizer [Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) would be one such optimization.

Comment: By returning the vector, I thought I would create another copy of it. This, I thought, would be inefficient, hence the iterator being returned. Is there any way to use the function and not be inefficient, however implausible it may be?

Comment: @SriPrasanna As mentioned, copy elision will kick in and it's very likely no copy will be made if you return your local vector.  Even if the copy isn't elided, the value returned from the function is an rvalue, so it can be moved instead of copying.  That requires only a cheap pointer copy, rather than copying the entire contents of the vector.

Comment: @SriPrasanna Trust me, no modern compiler will make it inefficient. Compilers these days are very good at *eliding* such copies (see my previous comment).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! returning the vector works, and is quite a bit more simple. must've over-thought this.